# Removing functions from Woocommerce hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This will probably open a door for me as there's something I'm missing so a WooCommerce 101 please;

part of the WooCommerce template archive-product.php contains the code;

```
    <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>
```

From this, and reading the documentation, it implies that this;

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
```

should remove the result count from the product categories returned. Only it doesn't.

What's wrong?

Comment: 1. remove the result count from the archive-product pages
2. understand how hooks and actions work (as it seems a fundamental part of templating in woo commerce)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was going to say you should read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) but it is leaving an important part out.

`remove_action()` cannot be called directly and must, itself, be added to an action hook. The action hook needs to come before the action being removed. In this case I would just use the same hook, but an earlier priority (default is 10, I've used 1)

```
function so_38878702_remove_hook(){
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'so_38878702_remove_hook', 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning to understand this important technique now. And it's true that it is not mentioned in the Wordpress documentation.

Comment: I just added it to the Codex. Though I think they are moving over to developer.wordpress.org.

Answer (score 5):

To `remove result count` action from Woocommerce -

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'remove_result_count' );
    function remove_result_count()
    {
         remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);
      
    }
```

use this code in your **function.php** file.

> **Important**: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority
> arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both
> filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action
>
> Here you can get WooCommerce **Action and Filter Hook** -
>
> https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html